# Bug em Validação com javascript

Tags: javascript, formulário

Tenho uma pagina de registrar pedido, onde se o usuario selecionar a opção "não" no checkbox, significa que o pedido é para entrega se ele selecionar "sim", ele vem retirar o produto na loja. Porém acontece um bug se o usuario preenche todos os dados de entrega primeiro e somente depois seleciona a opção "nao", a função javascript apaga os dados que foram digitado/selecionados nos campos do formulario. Segue código javaScript.

```
$(document).on("change", "input[type=radio]", function() {
  rdRetirar = $('[name="rdRetirar"]:checked').val();
  rdIdem = $('[name="rdDestinaIdemReme"]:checked').val();

  if (rdIdem == "sim") {
    var selremetente = $('#selremetente').val();
    $('#seldestinatario').val(selremetente);
    $('#seldestinatario').prop("required", false);
    var txtemail = $('#txtemail').val();
    $('#txtemaild').val(txtemail);
    var telefone1 = $('#telefone1').val();
    $('#telefone1d').val(telefone1);
    var telefone2 = $('#telefone2').val();
    $('#telefone2d').val(telefone2);
    var selEstado = $('#selEstado').val();
    $('#selEstadod').val(selEstado);
    $('#selEstadod').prop("required", false);
    var selCidade = $('#selCidade').val();
    $('#selCidaded').val(selCidade);
    $('#selCidaded').prop("required", false);
    var selBairro = $('#selBairro').val();
    $('#selBairrod').val(selBairro);
    $('#selBairrod').prop("required", false);
    var logradouro = $('#txtlogradouro').val();
    $('#logradourod').val(logradouro);
    var numero = $('#txtnumero').val();
    $('#numerod').val(numero);
    var complemento = $('#complemento').val();
    $('#complementod').val(complemento);

    if (selEstado == "") {
      alert("Favor preencher o campo Estado na seção do Remetente!");
      $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
      $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
    } else if (selCidade == "") {
      alert("Favor preencher o campo Cidade na seção do Remetente!");
      $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
      $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
    } else if (selBairro == "") {
      alert("Favor preencher o campo Bairro na seção do Remetente!");
      $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
      $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
    } else if ((logradouro == "") && (complemento == "")) {
      alert("Favor preencher o campo Logradouro ou Complemento na seção do Remetente!");
      $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
      $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
    } else if ((numero == "") && (complemento == "")) {
      alert("Favor preencher o campo Número ou Complemento na seção do Remetente!");
      $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
      $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
    } else {
      $("#DivdoDestinatario").hide("slow");
      $("#DivdoDestinatarioCopiado").show("slow");
    }

  } else {
    $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
    $("#DivdoDestinatarioCopiado").hide();
    $('#seldestinatario').val("");
    $('#txtemaild').val("");
    $('#telefone1d').val("");
    $('#telefone2d').val("");
    $('#selEstadod').val("");
    $('#selCidaded').val("");
    $('#selBairrod').val("");
    $('#logradourod').val("");
    $('#numerod').val("");
    $('#complementod').val("");
    $('#seldestinatario').prop("required", true);
    $('#selEstadod').prop("required", true);
    $('#selCidaded').prop("required", true);
    $('#selBairrod').prop("required", true);
  }

  if (rdRetirar == 'sim') {
    $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeS').prop("disabled", true);

    $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeN').prop("disabled", true);

    $('#seldestinatario').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#txtemaild').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#telefone1d').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#telefone2d').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#selEstadod').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#selCidaded').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#selBairrod').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#logradourod').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#numerod').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#complementod').prop("disabled", true);
    //Desabilita os campos de relacionados a terceirizada
    $('#selTerceirizada').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#selVeiculo').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#txtvalortaxa').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#txtvalortaxa').val("0,00");
  } else {
    //Reabilita os campos do destinatario
    $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeS').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeN').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#seldestinatario').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#txtemaild').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#telefone1d').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#telefone1d').prop("required", true);
    $('#telefone2d').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#selEstadod').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#selCidaded').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#selBairrod').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#logradourod').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#numerod').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#complementod').prop("disabled", false);
    //Reabilita os campos de relacionados a terceirizada
    $('#selTerceirizada').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#selVeiculo').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#txtvalortaxa').prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Comment: O que é `rdIdem`? Por quê os valores são alterados para nulos quando `rdIdem != "sim"`?

Comment: voce esta explicitamente mandando apagar o conteudo digitado, acredito que precise rever sua logica...

Comment: `if (rdIdem == "sim") {...}else{ nesse trecho voce apaga o valor de todos os campos}` acredito que se voce remover esse else resolve seu problema.

Comment: @NeuberOliveira .Desculpem, mas nao é na condição do rdIdem, essa esta fazendo a função certamente, o problema ocorre em rdRetirar.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss rdIdem é quando o cara q ta comprando(remetente) nao comprou para dar de presente para outra pessoa entao o destinatário é igual(rdIdem) ao remetente.

Comment: Se ele marcar que é pra presente, depois preencher tudo e só depois selecionar "não" no retirar, o else onde você apaga tudo vai ser executado, concorda? Você tem que tratar os dois eventos separadamente, e não juntos no mesmo eventListener.

Comment: @luislhl verdade, não percebi que acontecia esse bug, pois como estava dentro de if's eu achei que isso não iria ocorrer. VLW. vou postar como resolvi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separei em eventListener diferentes, veja:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name="rdRetirar"]').on("change", function() {
        if (this.checked && this.value == 'sim') {
             rdRetirar = "sim";
          $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeS').prop("disabled", true);

          $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeN').prop("disabled", true);

          $('#seldestinatario').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#txtemaild').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#telefone1d').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#telefone2d').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#selEstadod').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#selCidaded').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#selBairrod').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#logradourod').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#numerod').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#complementod').prop("disabled", true);
          //Desabilita os campos de relacionados a terceirizada
          $('#selTerceirizada').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#selVeiculo').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#txtvalortaxa').prop("disabled", true);
          $('#txtvalortaxa').val("0,00");
        } else {
             rdRetirar = "nao";
            //Reabilita os campos do destinatario
          $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeS').prop("disabled", false);

          $('#rdDestinaIdemRemeN').prop("disabled", false);

          $('#seldestinatario').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#txtemaild').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#telefone1d').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#telefone1d').prop("required", true);
          $('#telefone2d').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#selEstadod').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#selCidaded').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#selBairrod').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#logradourod').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#numerod').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#complementod').prop("disabled", false);
          //Reabilita os campos de relacionados a terceirizada
          $('#selTerceirizada').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#selVeiculo').prop("disabled", false);
          $('#txtvalortaxa').prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name="rdDestinaIdemReme"]').on("change", function() {
        if (this.checked && this.value == 'sim') {
           var selremetente = $('#selremetente').val();
           $('#seldestinatario').val(selremetente);
           $('#seldestinatario').prop("required", false);
           var txtemail = $('#txtemail').val();
           $('#txtemaild').val(txtemail);
           var telefone1 = $('#telefone1').val();
           $('#telefone1d').val(telefone1);
           var telefone2 = $('#telefone2').val();
           $('#telefone2d').val(telefone2);
           var selEstado = $('#selEstado').val();
           $('#selEstadod').val(selEstado);
           $('#selEstadod').prop("required", false);
           var selCidade = $('#selCidade').val();
           $('#selCidaded').val(selCidade);
           $('#selCidaded').prop("required", false);
           var selBairro = $('#selBairro').val();
           $('#selBairrod').val(selBairro);
           $('#selBairrod').prop("required", false);
           var logradouro = $('#txtlogradouro').val();
           $('#logradourod').val(logradouro);
           var numero = $('#txtnumero').val();
           $('#numerod').val(numero);
           var complemento = $('#complemento').val();
           $('#complementod').val(complemento);



           if(selEstado==""){
             alert("Favor preencher o campo Estado na seção do Remetente!");
             $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
             $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
           }else if(selCidade==""){
             alert("Favor preencher o campo Cidade na seção do Remetente!");
             $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
             $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
             }else if(selBairro==""){
               alert("Favor preencher o campo Bairro na seção do Remetente!");
               $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
               $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
               }else if((logradouro=="") && (complemento=="")){
                 alert("Favor preencher o campo Logradouro ou Complemento na seção do Remetente!");
                 $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
                 $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
                 }else if((numero=="") &&(complemento=="")){
                   alert("Favor preencher o campo Número ou Complemento na seção do Remetente!");
                   $("#rdDestinaIdemRemeN").prop("checked", true);
                   $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
                 }else{
                   $("#DivdoDestinatario").hide("slow");
                   $("#DivdoDestinatarioCopiado").show("slow");
                 }

        } else {
          $("#DivdoDestinatario").show("slow");
          $("#DivdoDestinatarioCopiado").hide();
          $('#seldestinatario').val("");
          $('#txtemaild').val("");
          $('#telefone1d').val("");
          $('#telefone2d').val("");
          $('#selEstadod').val("");
          $('#selCidaded').val("");
          $('#selBairrod').val("");
          $('#logradourod').val("");
          $('#numerod').val("");
          $('#complementod').val("");
          $('#seldestinatario').prop("required", true);
          $('#selEstadod').prop("required", true);
          $('#selCidaded').prop("required", true);
          $('#selBairrod').prop("required", true);
        }
    });
});
```